# XSLT: XML list with level to XML with recursive nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

My input is a company’s org. structure in XML, with multiple departments and there sub departments. The level of the sub department in the org. structure is given in tag LEVEL.

The output should also be XML with multiple departments. But now the sub departments should be in a recursive node. Both DepartmentList and SubDepartmentList consist of one or more Department (or zero), and Department has SubDepartmentList under Details.

The Tool I am using is only knows XSLT 1.0, so I hope it is possible to solve in this version.

Example on input (only 1 department):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Z_HR_HRM_SYNC_DEPARTMENTS>
    <IT_ORG>
        <item>
            <ORGEH>50013998</ORGEH>
            <ORGEH_PARENT>50000025</ORGEH_PARENT>
            <TITLE>Title 50013998</TITLE>
            <SUB_DEP>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50014000</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50013998</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50014000</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50000849</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50013998</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50000849</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50017825</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50000849</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50017825</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50001684</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50000849</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50001684</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50012716</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50000849</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50012716</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50001709</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50012716</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50001709</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50012713</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50000849</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50012713</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50001694</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50000849</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50001694</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50010284</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50001694</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50010284</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50001695</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50001694</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50001695</TITLE>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <LEVEL>4</LEVEL>
                    <ORGEH>50001697</ORGEH>
                    <ORGEH_PARENT>50001695</ORGEH_PARENT>
                    <TITLE>Title 50001697</TITLE>
                </item>
            </SUB_DEP>
        </item>
    </IT_ORG>
</Z_HR_HRM_SYNC_DEPARTMENTS>
```

The corresponding output made by hand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:BatchSyncDepartments xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.hr-manager.net/remoting/1.0/">
<ns1:request>
    <ns1:DepartmentList>
        <ns1:Department>
            <ns1:Id>
                <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50013998</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
            </ns1:Id>
            <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50000025</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
            </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
            <ns1:Title>Title 50013998</ns1:Title>
            <ns1:Details>
                <ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                    <ns1:Department>
                        <ns1:Id>
                            <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50014000</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                        </ns1:Id>
                        <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                            <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50013998</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                        </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                        <ns1:Title>Title 50014000</ns1:Title>
                        <ns1:Details>
                            <ns1:SubDepartmentList/>
                        </ns1:Details>
                    </ns1:Department>
                    <ns1:Department>
                        <ns1:Id>
                            <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50000849</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                        </ns1:Id>
                        <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                            <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50013998</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                        </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                        <ns1:Title>Title 50000849</ns1:Title>
                        <ns1:Details>
                            <ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                                <ns1:Department>
                                    <ns1:Id>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50017825</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:Id>
                                    <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50000849</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                    <ns1:Title>Title 50017825</ns1:Title>
                                    <ns1:Details>
                                        <ns1:SubDepartmentList/>
                                    </ns1:Details>
                                </ns1:Department>
                                <ns1:Department>
                                    <ns1:Id>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50001684</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:Id>
                                    <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50000849</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                    <ns1:Title>Title 50001684</ns1:Title>
                                    <ns1:Details>
                                        <ns1:SubDepartmentList/>
                                    </ns1:Details>
                                </ns1:Department>
                                <ns1:Department>
                                    <ns1:Id>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50012716</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:Id>
                                    <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50000849</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                    <ns1:Title>Title 50012716</ns1:Title>
                                    <ns1:Details>
                                        <ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                                            <ns1:Department>
                                                <ns1:Id>
                                                    <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50001709</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                                </ns1:Id>
                                                <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                                    <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50012716</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                                </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                                <ns1:Title>Title 50001709</ns1:Title>
                                                <ns1:Details>
                                                    <ns1:SubDepartmentList/>
                                                </ns1:Details>
                                            </ns1:Department>
                                        </ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                                    </ns1:Details>
                                </ns1:Department>
                                <ns1:Department>
                                    <ns1:Id>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50012713</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:Id>
                                    <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50000849</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                    <ns1:Title>Title 50012713</ns1:Title>
                                    <ns1:Details>
                                        <ns1:SubDepartmentList/>
                                    </ns1:Details>
                                </ns1:Department>
                                <ns1:Department>
                                    <ns1:Id>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50001694</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:Id>
                                    <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                        <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50000849</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                    </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                    <ns1:Title>Title 50001694</ns1:Title>
                                    <ns1:Details>
                                        <ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                                            <ns1:Department>
                                                <ns1:Id>
                                                    <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50010284</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                                </ns1:Id>
                                                <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                                    <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50001694</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                                </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                                <ns1:Title>Title 50010284</ns1:Title>
                                                <ns1:Details>
                                                    <ns1:SubDepartmentList/>
                                                </ns1:Details>
                                            </ns1:Department>
                                            <ns1:Department>
                                                <ns1:Id>
                                                    <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50001695</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                                </ns1:Id>
                                                <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                                    <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50001694</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                                </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                                <ns1:Title>Title 50001695</ns1:Title>
                                                <ns1:Details>
                                                    <ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                                                        <ns1:Department>
                                                            <ns1:Id>
                                                                <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50001697</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                                            </ns1:Id>
                                                            <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                                                <ns1:ThirdPartyId>50001695</ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                                            </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                                                            <ns1:Title>Title 50001697</ns1:Title>
                                                            <ns1:Details>
                                                                <ns1:SubDepartmentList/>
                                                            </ns1:Details>
                                                        </ns1:Department>
                                                    </ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                                                </ns1:Details>
                                            </ns1:Department>
                                        </ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                                    </ns1:Details>
                                </ns1:Department>
                            </ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                        </ns1:Details>
                    </ns1:Department>
                </ns1:SubDepartmentList>
            </ns1:Details>
        </ns1:Department>
    </ns1:DepartmentList>
</ns1:request>
</ns1:BatchSyncDepartments>
```

I am quit new to XSLT and have only solved the simple stuff, but now I am stuck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="Z_HR_HRM_SYNC_DEPARTMENTS">
    <ns1:BatchSyncDepartments xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.hr-manager.net/remoting/1.0/">
        <ns1:request>
            <ns1:DepartmentList>
                <xsl:for-each select="IT_ORG/item">
                    <ns1:Department>
                        <ns1:Id>
                            <ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ORGEH"/>
                            </ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                        </ns1:Id>
                        <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                            <ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ORGEH_PARENT"/>
                            </ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                        </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
                        <ns1:Title>
                            <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
                        </ns1:Title>
                        <ns1:Details>
                            <ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                            </ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                        </ns1:Details>
                    </ns1:Department>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ns1:DepartmentList>
        </ns1:request>
    </ns1:BatchSyncDepartments>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope someone can help with some input how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But now the sub departments should be in a recursive node.

For this, you should adopt a recursive processing approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.hr-manager.net/remoting/1.0/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="item" use="ORGEH_PARENT" />

<xsl:template match="Z_HR_HRM_SYNC_DEPARTMENTS">
    <ns1:BatchSyncDepartments xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.hr-manager.net/remoting/1.0/">
        <ns1:request>
            <ns1:DepartmentList>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="IT_ORG/item"/>
            </ns1:DepartmentList>
        </ns1:request>
    </ns1:BatchSyncDepartments>  
</xsl:template>             

 <xsl:template match="item">
    <ns1:Department>
        <ns1:Id>
            <ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                <xsl:value-of select="ORGEH"/>
            </ns1:ThirdPartyId>
        </ns1:Id>
        <ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
            <ns1:ThirdPartyId>
                <xsl:value-of select="ORGEH_PARENT"/>
            </ns1:ThirdPartyId>
        </ns1:ParentDepartmentId>
        <ns1:Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
        </ns1:Title>
        <ns1:Details>
            <ns1:SubDepartmentList>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', ORGEH)"/>
            </ns1:SubDepartmentList>
        </ns1:Details>
    </ns1:Department>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfect. I hoped it could be done in a short and nice way - but with my limited experience, it was not possible. It is always nice when somebody with experience will help.